# sqlite summing up rows and getting total in new column

Tags: sqlite

how do I add the first row from "col1" to the next row in col1...  so it shows new "total_col" like below

this data

```
 date    col_1  
 jan-1   10     
 jan-2   25    
 jan-3   33     
 jan-4   -12    
 jan-5   20
```

to show this

```
 date    col_1  total_col
 jan-1   10     10
 jan-2   25     35
 jan-3   33     68
 jan-4   -12    56
 jan-5   20     76
```

Comment: SQL tables are unordered. Please specify how to determine the "next" row.

Comment: I do not understand ...."SQL tables are unordered"  and also do not know how to  "determine the next row" . My table do not have primary keys or id number columns

Comment: In what order do you want the rows to be displayed?

Comment: I want the rows display as it is... following what that is in col_1('row1'), col_1('row2'), col_1('row3'), to total_col (row1 = col_1('row1'), row2 = col_1('row1' +'row2' ), row3 = col_1('row2' + row3''), )

Comment: There is no such thing as "as is". Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby).

Comment: if i have a date column would it help?

Comment: Any column that you can sort by would help.

Comment: how could i code sqlite to give the above result

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I obtain value of "col_1" from resultset and loop through it with "+=". It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the cumulative sum, it would be possible to add up all rows with a smaller date:

```
SELECT date,
       col1,
       (SELECT sum(col1)
        FROM MyTable AS T2
        WHERE T2.date <= MyTable.date
       ) AS total_col
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY date;
```

This requires that the values in the `date` column can be compared correctly, i.e., that they use one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

It might be a better idea to do the summing in your application.